# How to map a SQL view with a one to many query to a parent and children class with EF Core

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

If I use the following view with ef core, how can I map this into a parent-child (nested object) class? Selecting from this view will give duplicate entries for specific blogs when a blog has more than 1 post.

```sql
CREATE VIEW View_BlogPosts AS
  SELECT b.Name, p.PostId
  FROM Blogs b
  LEFT JOIN Posts p on p.BlogId = b.BlogId
```

I am trying to get results into a json like this:

```json
{
  "blogId": 1,
  "blogTitle": "My Tech Blog",
  "posts": [
    {
      "postId": 101,
      "postTitle": "Introduction to Programming",
      "content": "In this post, we'll discuss the basics of programming..."
    },
    {
      "postId": 102,
      "postTitle": "Advanced Web Development",
      "content": "Learn about the latest trends in web development..."
    }
  ]
}
```

So the class would be like:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I don't think grouping is the best solution. Instead something like navigational properties for normal entities would be ideal.

Note: This is not my real query, I cannot migrate the whole thing to direct ef with navigational properties due to its complexity. Only option is to opt out the one to many entities from the view and join them to view from managed code.

Before that, if there are good suggestions, I would like to get some ideas. Thanks!!

Comment: Does the view output other column?

Comment: No, it only returns specific columns from all joined tables @vernou

Comment: EF can only do that if you query the original tables and use a navigation property `blog.Posts` in the LINQ query.